# Bug in rep calculation

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

Here's the situation.  I've capped out my rep for the day, with plenty of votes to spare.  My rep is, say, 1000.  I make a horribly stupid answer and get two downvotes.  My rep now shows 996.  I delete the answer and go to stackoverflow.com/reputation and click the recalc button.  Now I'm back to 1000; all is well.

I realize I've spent too much time on Stack Overflow, and get back to work.  Someone then upvotes a previous answer, and my rep goes to **1004**.  The /reputation tab is still correct, and shows 1000, but the site thinks it needs to compensate me for the previous downvotes, even though that answer is deleted.

Has this been reported previously?

Comment: That's exactly why I often recalc only near before end of day or after I got compensation votes :)

Comment: @Chichiray - lesson learned :)  But is the team aware of this?

Comment: Undoubtely. Reputation is hold in different (cached) sources. So there's risk that you see a discrepancy elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed along with most other reputation bugs as part of [the latest reputation code refactor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes), live on meta and being deployed across the network soon.